# WIB/WML bytecode conversion

Tags: smartcard, sim-card, wml

I need to convert WML into bytecode before sending it to SIM card via SMPP (i.e. SMS OTA). However, I am not able to find any specifications or tools to help me do the conversion.

After some search, There was a tool called Transformer Pro by SmartTrust but seems obsolete. Another tool is available called WAC but does not show the bytecode generated.

Are these specifications proprietary to SmartTrust (G&D)? Did anybody succeed in converting WML to bytecode ?

any help is appreciated.

Comment: *bytecode* is a very ambiguous term. Do you have a specific reference specifying the desired format?

Comment: There seems to be a proprietary way to convert the WML to bytecode, you may think of it analogous to WBXML. The specifications seems private to SmartTrust but there are some tools (Transformer pro) which turned up to be obsolete.

Comment: Post your WML I will try and assist with the conversion. WAC does the conversion buy only the "network operator" version